# rename column ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

Trying to rename a column in ClickHouse. According to the documentation:

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/column/#alter_rename-column

```
ALTER TABLE visits RENAME COLUMN webBrowser TO browser
```

Although, it should be easy as 123 but I keep receiving the same error.

Note: using the latest version of ClickHouse.

Error:

```
Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 29: RENAME COLUMN crid TO crId. Expected one of: CLEAR COLUMN, FETCH PARTITION, ATTACH PARTITION, ADD INDEX, DROP INDEX, ALTER command, UPDATE, MATERIALIZE INDEX, ADD CONSTRAINT, MATERIALIZE TTL, a list of ALTER commands, COMMENT COLUMN, MODIFY TTL, MOVE PART, DROP COLUMN, MOVE PARTITION, MODIFY COLUMN, DROP PARTITION, ON, DELETE WHERE, ADD COLUMN, CLEAR INDEX, DROP CONSTRAINT, DETACH PARTITION, REPLACE PARTITION, MODIFY ORDER BY, ATTACH PART, FREEZE, DROP DETACHED PART, MODIFY SETTING, DROP DETACHED PARTITION, MODIFY QUERY (version 20.3.4.10 (official build))
```

Anyone care to shine some light on this issue.

-------------------------- **UPDATE** -------------------------

So I thought I was updated to the latest version of clickHouse.

```
clickhouse-server --version
```

ClickHouse server version 21.7.5.29 (official build).

The issue was that after updating ClickHouse it didn't restart properly. My solution was to restart ClickHouse server and boom the new RENAME feature worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your CH version: `select version()`

`rename column` was added in CH 20.5.
Currently supported versions are 21.3, 21.5, 21.6, 21.7